# Evaluate Sheet name indirectly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Within the strict context of vanilla google sheets, I would like to check if there is a way to dynamically address a Sheet by name.

For instance, if one of my sheets is named "foo's great", I can access it in a formula by the following:

```
=COUNT('foo''s great'!A2:A500)
```

Now, let's say I want to stop hardcode the sheet name and want to use a cell containing that sheet name, resolve it to the sheet name, and do my things.

Something along those lines:

```
=COUNT(EVALUATE_RESOLVE(Z1)!A2:A500)
```

Where the cell Z1 contains a String, resolving to an existing sheet name within the workbook.

Comment: INDIRECT: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula would be:

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT(Z1&"!A2:A500"))
```

where cell **Z1** contains a valid sheet name